# Python Read dataset from CSV

Tags: java, python, r

I have done a small project but do not know how to read from the csv dataset file and how to return the values ​​as in the description, I hope you can help me.
Once again many thanks.I was attached link google drive contain the file dataset and description.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16fU_g9jevu-A6Laxs1zeeZNzjGW73KQ4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this might be helpful https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html.

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python "Pandas" framework:

```py
import pandas as pd

f = "path/to/your/file.csv"
dataframe = pd.read_csv(f)
# handle your data
```

Pandas gives you a lot of functionalities to handle and manage the dataset.

Or you can use the standard csv writer.

```py
import csv

file = "path/to/your/file.csv"
with open(file, "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
    # handle your data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```py
import csv
with open('myfile') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for details in reader:
        #retrieve your data
```

I had to do something similar before but with emails and names. I had a csv like this:
[pic of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Hr8.png)

Then I used this code

```py
import csv
with open("emails.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)
    for name, email in reader:
        #sent each person a personalized email here
```